Should the same environmental variable measured with different methods be removed before K-means? What about variables repr. sep. and by their ratio?
So I'm running K-means clustering algorithm on environmental variables measured on different locations. The aim is to see if the environmental variables can be clustered into separate clusters.
Same variable measured with two different techniques
One of the variables, N, has been measured using 2 different techniques. That resulted in 2 sets of measurements for N. For the other variables only one technique has been used per variable. Due to this I feel that N is overrepresented compared to the other variables, and would get to much weight. Another way of looking at this is that N values measured with technique 1 and 2, are highly correlated. This could be another reason from removing the measurements of N from one of the techniques before running K-means. So should I remove the measurents of N from one of the techniques before running K-means?
Variables represented separately and as ratios
In addition I have the ratio N:P in the dataset I got from the lab. Within the same dataset N and P are also provided as separate variables. I'm not specifically studying the ratio, rather the indivdual variables. I feel that there is "duplicate info" in the dataset if I include the ratio together with N and P before running K-means. But since it is a ratio, it wouldn't necessarily be highly correlated with the individual variables (N, P). So should I remove the N:P ratio before running K-means?
